# Finding the basis and dimension of kerT and imT for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $F: \Bbb R[t]_2 \longrightarrow\Bbb R[t]_4$ given by $F\bigl(p(t)\bigr)= t^2p(t)$.

To find $\ker F$ I suppose I need to find the solutions for the following equation

$$F(a + bt+ct^2) = at^2 + bt^3 + ct^4 = 0.$$

The solution I find in the back of the book says $\ker F = \{0\}$. But how is that possible if the equation $at^2 + bt^3 + ct^4 = 0$ has other solutions apart from $0$?

What about $\operatorname{Im}F$? Do I need to find a generator set from $at^2 + bt^3 + ct^4$?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is $\{0\}$ because $a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2\in\ker F\iff F(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2)=0$. But$$F(a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2)=a_0t^2+a_1t^3+a_2t^4,$$which is the null *polynomial* if and only if $a_0=a_1=a_2=0$. The existence of roots of $a_0t^2+a_1t^3+a_2t^4$ doesn't matter here.

And $\operatorname{Im}F$ is the set of those elements of $\Bbb R[t]_4$ of the form $a_0t^2+a_1t^3+a_2t^4$. In other words,$$\operatorname{Im}F=\{P(t)\in\Bbb R[t]_4\mid P(0)=P'(0)=0\}.$$

Comment: Can you please explain why 02+13+24 is the null polynomial if and only if 0=1=2=0?

Comment: Because the null polynomial is *by definition* the polynomial $0+0\times t+\cdots+0\times t^n$. How do *you* define the null polynomial?

Comment: Oh I see. I was thinking that the variable t could assume the value 0 and the coefficients could assume any other value.

Comment: We are talking about *polynomials*, not about polynomial *functions*.

Comment: Can you please explain more about how to find the Im F? In the back of the book the solution says ImF = {tˆ2, tˆ3, tˆ4}, which in my head makes sense, because for any a_0, a_1, a_2 real we have that image. What you meant when you wrote  P(0) = P'(0) = 0?

Comment: The set $\{t^2,t^3,t^4\}$ is a *basis* of $\operatorname{Im}F$. And a polynomial $P(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\cdots+a_nt^n$ is such that $a_0=a_1=0$ if and only if $P(0)=P'(0)=0$, since $P(0)=a_0$ and $P'(0)=a_1$.